# Sum of sines and their products

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $g(m,n)$ be defined by

> $$g(m,n):=\begin{cases}
>  \sin ^2(m) & \text{if} \ m=n & \\ 
> \sin (n)-\sin (m) & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$

Is it possible to prove by Lagrange interpolation, or otherwise that

> $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \sin (\sin (n)) \prod _{m
> =1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin (m)}{g(n,m)}=1$$

The product is not well-behaved meaning it oscillates, but if the two expressions are increased together the given value is reached...What can be said about such a series? I'm sorry if the question is too obscure.

Comment: Latex tip : use "cases" for describing a list of choices.

Comment: Not obscure, but definitely unclear. "if the two expressions are increased together..." – what does that mean? Which two expressions? Increased in what sense?

Comment: Oh you again. Hi, sorry for that. It means the product and the sum increased together, meaning the number of terms. Mathematicians understand so many things but simple pedestrian language is so hard for them. Anyway sorry.

Comment: @Gerry This question seems easy to prove to me. But I cant prove it...

Comment: So what is meant is actually:
$$\lim_{N\nearrow \infty}\sum _{n=1}^{N} \sin (\sin (n)) \prod _{m
=1}^{N } \frac{\sin (m)}{g(n,m)}=1$$ or 
$$\lim_{N\nearrow \infty}\sum _{n=1}^{N} \sin (\sin (n)) \prod _{m
=1}^{N } \frac{\sin (m)}{g(N,m)}=1$$

Comment: Yes that is bad. No the first one is correct, not the second. The N in g is a small n. I hope you can prove/disprove it.